# How to set an input field to ng-invalid in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input

I would like to check an input field for credit card numbers.

The field should remain invalid until it has a minimum length of 13. As the user should be able to fill in space into the field, I remove those spaces within a javascript function.
In this function I would like to check the credit card number (without spaces) and set it to ng-invalid as long as the minimum length is lesser than 13 and the maximum length is greater than 16.

It should be something like this:

```
$scope.ccHandler = function() {
   if ($scope.ccNumber == '') {
      document.getElementById("ccProvider").disabled = false;
   }
   $scope.ccNumber = inputCC.value.split(' ').join(''); //entfernt die Leerzeichen aus der Kreditkartennummer vor der übergabe an den Server
   console.log("das ist meine CC: " + $scope.ccNumber);
   isValidCreditCardNumber($scope.ccNumber);
   getCreditCardProvider($scope.ccNumber);
   document.getElementById("ccProvider").disabled = true;
   if ($scope.ccNumber.length < creditCardNumberMinLength || $scope.ccNumber.length > creditCardNumberMaxLength) {
      //$scope.ccNumber.ng-invalid = true;
      console.log("ccNumber ist noch ungültig!");
      //document.getElementById("inputCC").$setValidity("ccNumber", false);
   }
}
```

This would be the part of the XHTML:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-switch-when="CreditCard">
   <label class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Kreditkartennummer</label> 
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <input name="ccNumber" class="form-control" type="text" id="inputCC" ng-change="ccHandler();updateCount()" ng-model="ccNumber" ng-required="true"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please use `ng-disabled` instead of `document.getElementById("ccProvider").disabled`

Comment: You might want to check out the mask directive of angular ui: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/mask

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
$scope.myForm.ccNumber.$setValidity("ccNumber", false);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is an answer to my post as it achieves what I searched for.

Comment: You are right, I didn't use $setValidity correctly. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 33):

You can do that with `$setValidity`. You need to set a `name` attribute on the `<form>` for this to work.

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input name="ccNumber" ng-model="ccNumber">
   <span ng-show="myForm.ccNumber.$error.minLength">
      A cc number should be minimum 10 chars
   </span>
</form>
```

Then you can manually set the validity with

```
$scope.myForm.ccNumber.$setValidity("minLength",$scope.ccNumber.length>=10);
```

Here is a working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7J326LR194SaoE2TmHuU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for that. Somehow setting validity this way it is ignored somehow. I don´t know why. The input field is within a div, and this div is within the form. That should be ok, doesn´t it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard `ng-maxlength` and `ng-minlength` attributes on your input field.

There is a working example in the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

```
 <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.last" 
     ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
```

Comment: Thank you, but that I cannot use as spaces are removed within that input field (as I mentioned above). I need to track the length within a JS-function.
I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Why can't you remove the spaces and let the standard directives set the validity in the end?

Comment: The spaces are removed but the actual input within the field is being observed by ng-minlength and ng-maxlength and not the data being changed without spaces. So the problem is that those spaces are taken into account when checking min and max length.