# AngularJS bind ng-valid with function

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-forms

Hi i would like to setValidity of input using an expression, but not a regEx, something like this

```
<input ng-model="number" required ng-valid="number / 2 > 14">
```

Is it possible i have complex function and i don't know how to convert it into regEx so i would like to use something like this. I try to use this library: https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator but it doesn't work at all :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982647/how-to-set-an-input-field-to-ng-invalid-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input ng-model="number" required ng-keyup="checkValid(number)">
        <span style="color:red" ng-if="!isValid">Not a valid number</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And create a function like following:

```
(function(){

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){
        $scope.isValid = true;

      $scope.checkValid = function(value){
        if(value){
            if(value/2>14){
            $scope.isValid = true;
          }else{
            $scope.isValid = false;
          }
        }
      }  


    });

})();
```